# Как вызвать приложение без указывания пути или добавления в папку Bin\Debug

Tags: c#

Не нашёл информации на эту тему.

Пример: допустим, я делаю приложение, которое запускает ещё ряд приложений. И многие пишут, что нужно использовать `Process.Start(@"Путь")` или скидывать приложениe(exe) в Bin\Debaug.
Можно ли обратиться к "чему-то", чтобы Windows доставал(находил) приложение сам?
*Например: Process.Start("Steam.exe") и просто запускается стим*. Чтобы не было привязки к пути, если вдруг приложение будет в другом месте храниться.

Если коротко, то вызов приложения - наплевав на путь) и на Bin\Debaug, и т. д.

*Я новичок в этом ремесле :3 многое не понимаю. Заранее спасибо :D*

Comment: И да и Нет. Более развернуто: Каждое приложение индивидуально, имеет свой функционал, свои механизмы запуска, ну и так далее. Из Windows можно достать список установленных приложений (те, что вы видите в "удалении программ", если там его не будет, то и получить путь вы не сможете. Еще вариант, это если у приложения есть зарегистрированный шорткат, у стима допустим есть - `steam://`, но не каждое приложение себе его делает. Ну и последний способ, варварский - просканировать все диски и найти нужный .exe, но, а если его переименовали? Так что, не каждое приложение вы сможете запустить без пути.

Comment: Есть еще переменные окружения, та же path. Если приложения туда себя добавляют - их там можно найти. Есть еще реестр. Есть файловые ассоциации. Короче вариантов масса. Но чтобы что то советовать, надо знать вашу задачу,  Вы ее не рассказали.

Comment: Чтобы винда находила сама, надо прописать в переменную PATH директорию экзешника. Если она прописана и вы хотите это использовать, используйте запуск через щелл `UseShellExecute = true` для `ProcessStartInfo`. А так, черт его знает, что вам там на самом деле нужно, на этот вопрос можно ответить кучу всякого, и не угадать того что вы спрашиваете. Конкретизируйте вопрос, отредактируйте его.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо! Я для себя делаю приложение и просто впитываю информацию :3 а так в общем понял.